# Quarkus: Use permissions instead of roles in JWT

Tags: permissions, jwt, roles, quarkus

We’re planning to use JWT to parse the permissions of a user to a microservice. But I was not able to find a solution to work only on the base of permissions with Quarkus. In this article, they are focusing strong on roles that are existing in every service: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt

Is there a way to implement only permission-based authorization in Quarkus based on JWT?

**Background:**

We’re having a decoupled multi-tenant Self-Contained Service structure that is optimized that we can easily integrate every SCS as an own service in another ecosystem. For that we have designed an authorization service that is keeping all tenants and roles. Every SCS manages his own permissions, but not roles. They are register to the authorization service and exposing all permissions to him. Inside the authorization service, the permissions will be grouped to roles, so that we can assign users more easily the permissions.

But for the authorization in every SCS, we want to use only permissions so that the SCS don’t have to know / manage the roles. The service knows the provided permissions and can match it against the provided JWT permissions.

We would like to send the following JWT:

```
{
"UserData":{
   "userId":#{USER_ID},
   "email":"#{USER_EMAIL},
   "tenants": {
      "#{TENANTS_NAME}":{
         "permissions": {
            "#{PERMISSION_NAME}",
            "#{PERMISSION_NAME}"
         },
      },
   },
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

application.properties:

```
permissions.permission1=role1
permissions.permission2=role2
permissions.permission3=role3
```

```java
import io.quarkus.security.identity.AuthenticationRequestContext;
import io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity;
import io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentityAugmentor;
import io.quarkus.security.runtime.QuarkusSecurityIdentity;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken;

@ApplicationScoped
public class JwtRoleMapper implements SecurityIdentityAugmentor {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "permissions")
    Map<String, String> permissionMappings;

    @Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> augment(SecurityIdentity identity, AuthenticationRequestContext authenticationRequestContext) {
        var jwt = (JsonWebToken) identity.getPrincipal();
        var tenants = (JsonObject) jwt.getClaim("tenants");        
        var builder = QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder(identity);

        tenants.getJsonObject("tenant_name").getJsonArray("permissions").forEach(permission -> 
            var role = this.permissionMappings.get(permission.toString());
            if (role != null && !role.isBlank())
                builder.addRole(role)
        );
        return Uni.createFrom().item(builder.build());
    }
}
```

You get the idea: retrieve the original JWT, get the tenants, iterate through it and map it to some roles defined in your config.